# RPi4 Network Boot: Configuration Error or Bug?

Tags: boot, networking, permissions, raspberrypi, nfs

I am trying to netboot Ubuntu 22.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4B (RPi4) using NFSv4. I have been trying this literally for months (previously with 20.04). I am beginning to wonder whether it is a bug in Ubuntu and would appreciate some help in deciding whether this is the case.

My NFSv4 server is a Synology NAS. If I boot my RPi4 from an SD card with Ubuntu 22.04 I can use NFSv4 to mount my *system-boot* and *writable* partitions from the NFSv4 server.

However, the only way I have found to perform a netboot successfully is by telling TFTP to use NFSv3. My current working *cmdline.txt* looks like this:

```
net.ifnames=0 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1
root=/dev/nfs
nfsrootdebug
nfsroot=192.168.8.20:/volume3/nfs/RPi4/Ubuntu/jammy/root
nfsvers=4
rootfstype=nfs4
rw ip=dhcp rootwait
```

(The newlines are only for legibility.)

As you can see, I have tried to specify that I want to use NFSv4 by specifying *nfsvers=4* and *rootfstype=nfs4*, but these are resolutely ignored (here probably because the form of the *nfsroot* is specifically NFSv3 – see below).

Here is my */etc/exports* on the NAS server:

```
/volume3/nfs    *(fsid=0,rw,no_subtree_check,sync)
/volume3/nfs/RPi4   *(rw,async,no_wdelay,crossmnt,insecure,no_root_squash,insecure_locks,sec=sys,anonuid=1025,anongid=100)
/volume3/nfs/RPi4/Ubuntu/jammy/boot *(rw,async,no_wdelay,crossmnt,insecure,no_root_squash,insecure_locks,sec=sys,anonuid=1025,anongid=100)
/volume3/nfs/RPi4/Ubuntu/jammy/root *(rw,async,no_wdelay,crossmnt,insecure,no_root_squash,insecure_locks,sec=sys,anonuid=1025,anongid=100)
```

(The parameters are generated mainly by the Synology admin interface and I tend to copy and paste them when editing in *ssh*).

For NFSv4 the correct specification of the *nfsroot* folder is:

```
/RPi4/Ubuntu/jammy/root
```

but if I try to use that in the *cmdline.txt* above the server gives me *Permission denied* messages. This makes me think that whatever reads *cmdline.txt* only understands NFSv3.

In case it isn't obvious, I'm not entirely at home with NFSv4, which is why I would be grateful for assistance in determining whether this is a bug.

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu uses nfsmount to mount the NFS remote directory in the initrd. nfsmount (which is provided by klibc-utils) does not support NFSv4. See

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1954716
- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=409272

Comment: Thank you for this information. It restores my faith in my own sanity. I believe that RaspiOS can netboot with NFSv4. I’ll try to use RaspiOS TFTP to boot Ubuntu, with all the potential horrors that that might unleash :-)

Comment: Raspberry Pi OS can boot from NFSv4 because it doesn't use an initrd (nfsmount) but uses the kernel's built-in NFS root mount capabilities (CONFIG_ROOT_NFS).